# one to many mysql query

Tags: mysql, one-to-many

Hey guys sorry to ask but i need help with this query please I've been messing around with different solutions but so far have not been able to solve it myself.

I have 4 tables called `customer`, `figures`, `notes` and `lender`. They all have a field called `reference`, which is what I'm using to link them together. Customer is the primary table and there is only one record in the figures table for each customer so i can do:

```
select * From customer, figures
where customer.reference = figures.reference
```

However, there may be multiple notes and lender records for each customer. How can I link them to show only one record?

Ideally, there would be a way to display it as:

```
reference, name, figures, lender 1, lender 2, note 1, note 2, note 3
```

Comment: Sounds like a work for a CTE to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [group_concat()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat):

```
SELECT customer.reference, customer.name, figures.name, 
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT lender.name), 
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT notes.name) 
FROM customer 
JOIN figures ON figures.reference = customer.reference 
LEFT JOIN lender ON lender.reference = customer.reference 
LEFT JOIN notes ON notes.reference = customer.reference 
GROUP BY customer.reference;
```

Assuming that each of the tables has a field `name`, you should change it to whatever your columns are.